# When could broadcast variables change if ever?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I've been told that broadcast variables should be immutable.

I've however seen a code snippet in which a broadcast variable is used as a flag.

```
public class TestBroadcast {

  private static JavaStreamingContext jssc;
  private static volatile Broadcast<Boolean> done;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR);

    List<String> log = Arrays.asList("X", "X", "X");

    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Test").setMaster("local[2]");
    jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, Durations.seconds(1));
    done = jssc.sparkContext().broadcast(Boolean.FALSE);    // false in the beginning

    JavaRDD<String> _rdd = jssc.sparkContext().parallelize(log);
    Queue<JavaRDD<String>> queue = new LinkedList<>();
    queue.add(_rdd);
    JavaDStream<String> lines = jssc.queueStream(queue);

    lines.foreachRDD(
        rdd -> {
          rdd.foreachPartition(x -> System.out.println(done.getValue())); // executor get false
          done = jssc.sparkContext().broadcast(Boolean.TRUE); // driver set the variable to true
/*MARK*/  rdd.foreachPartition(x -> System.out.println(done.getValue())); // executor get true
        });

    jssc.start();

    jssc.awaitTermination();

  }

}
```

The broadcast variable changes on the line annotated with `/*MARK*/` ([original source](https://gist.github.com/hrchu/ea4a982f1ac44af699cf4f2496f4ece9#file-testbroadcast-java-L39)), why did this happen?

Answer (score 2):

Despite the same name `done` the two broadcast variables are different.

I must admit that I've never seen such use of broadcast variables (perhaps because it leads to wrong conclusions as your question seemed to have proved). And unless I'm mistaken the usage does not really add much since the boolean value is so tiny (that even without a broadcast variable would not have added up much to the serialized message payload).

What's even more unusual is that this is inside a Spark Streaming application that uses `foreachRDD` that happens on the driver and so can access the `JavaStreamingContext` which would not have been available on executors (would have led to `NullPointerException`).

---

As a matter of fact, the lifecycle of broadcast variables does allow for changing the value of a broadcast variable. Think of a broadcast variable as a handle to something that is available in the memory space of an executor that can get resolved to a value on demand.

You could use [unpersist](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast@unpersist():Unit) method on the driver (that will trigger "deletion on executors" message to be sent out to executors) and so the following `value` would get the broadcast value again (possibly changed from what it has been initially).

> **unpersist(): Unit** Asynchronously delete cached copies of this broadcast on the executors. If the broadcast is used after this is called, it will need to be re-sent to each executor.

For this particular case (with `foreachRDD`) it would not make much sense as `foreachRDD` introduces another layer where you can manipulate broadcast variables and submit Spark jobs.